# Error Class "App\Models\VerifyUser" not found in AuthController

Tags: php, laravel

AuthController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Mail\VerifyMail;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\VerifyUser;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;



class AuthController extends Controller
{

//

}
```

VerifyUser

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VerifyUser extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

The application is made with Laravel 8

do you have any idea what i'm doing wrong ? i get Error Class "App\Models\VerifyUser" not found in AuthController

Comment: Where is the file `VerifyUser.php` located? Also the namespace declared in `VerifyUser.php` (`namespace App\Models\User`) does not match the one imported (`use App\Models\VerifyUser`) in `AuthController`.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó VerifyUser.php is located in app/models/

Comment: Then the declared namespace should simply be `namespace App\Models`. i.e. Without `\User` at the end.

Comment: It worked . can you answer so i can choose your answer ascorrect?